# Julia - ERROR: IOError: could not spawn `code`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)

Tags: julia

I am trying to use the "ls" command in julia and it gave me this error inside shell.

```
shell> ls
ERROR: IOError: could not spawn `ls`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
```

In my environment variable, there is C:\Program Files\Julia-1.9.3\bin.
Appreciate help to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1):

You are on Windows and `ls` is not a standard Windows command. It is a Linux command. The easiest fix is to start Julia process using bash terminal under Windows (it is shipped eg. with git as Git\bin\bash.exe file, which most likely you have installed). Then going to shell with `;` will make `ls` work as bash recognizes this command.

Comment: If the OP is used to using PowerShell and wants to use those commands (it does accept `ls`), they can load it explicitly with `powershell` at the Julia shell prompt.

Comment: Agreed. I did not discuss this option because then it is not a "lightweight" solution anymore (you need to exit PowerShell, then you fall back to `shell>` and then you need to exit this mode to go back to Julia mode).